# 2nd gen package version with ancestor is failing with custom object with "protected" visibility

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, isv, feature-management

I'm having issues when **creating a package version with ancestor** that contains a custom object with visibility set to "Protected". Everytime I try I get this error:

`xxx: Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomEntityDefinition, component=01Ixxx, state=MANAGED_RELEASED`

This custom object was packaged first time as `Protected` (using the visibility tag in object-meta.xml file). When using the release version as ancestor (using `ancestorId` in sfdx-project.json) I get this error saying I can't change the `visibility from public to protected`.

I tried changing the object name, changing the namespace, creating a new package. It happens every time. None of the objects were never public, deployed with public tag nor made public via `FeatureManagemnet.changePersmission`

My setup:

- SFDX: sfdx-cli/7.53.0-839fc82926
- ISV org acting as dev hub with namespace registry
- Dev org with namespace registered

Issue logged in Github 
github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/368

Comment: Adding github issue here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/368

Comment: Comments are not for relevant question details. You should put the link in the question proper. Also, for clarification: does the object exist in the child package as well? Are you adding new fields/changing anything about the object?

Comment: Hello @sfdxfox, yes object exist in every version. And for debug purposes, I don't edit any metadata between the first version and the second one. Only the minor version is being changed and I add the ancestorId. I tested by creating a new test namespace and new package and new object (changed api name) and I didn't deploy the object anywhere. I just ran the sfdx force:package:version:create locally with the metadata already set with visibility protected. First version without ancestor gets created, second one with ancestor fails.

Comment: How did you fix this issue? @LucasEnnouchi

Comment: Unfortunately had to go with a 1st generation package. As you can see ticket is still open after 1 year. I couldn't wait.